# SCSS: icon font and text in anchor tag

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to use an icon font and text in an anchor tag and want it to change color on hover. I am using scss for styling.

My code so far is:

```
<span class="sidebar-list"><a href="#"><span class="icon-SpeechBubble">&nbsp;</span>Live Chat</a></span>
```

SCSS

```
 .sidebar-list {
     a {
         color:#8894a4;
         font-family:$font-GlobalFamily;
         font-size:13px

         &:hover {
             color:#fff;
             cursor:pointer;
             text-decoration:none;
         }
     }
 }

 .icon-SpeechBubble:before {
     content: "\e633";
     font-size:13px;
 }
```

The problem I am facign is that when I hover over the text the icon font doesn't highlight. Also, the text is picking up some random color that is not #8894a4. Is there a way I can fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess it's just a typo due to copy-paste....but just to be sure, after `font-size: 13px` it's missing the `;`, it's not valid when compiling the css code

Comment: You have to look somewhere else in your code to solve this issue, the code above is fine, http://jsfiddle.net/c73smhbf/ Are you using frameworks (like tw bootstrap...) or external css (not yours)? Inspect the element to see what's wrong and if your code is there and it's not overridden by other classes

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
&:hover:before {
    color: *;
}
```